# How to read Chinese characters in text file using `readLines`

Tags: r, utf-8, chinese-locale

I want to read text in one line at a time.  The file is found in an online repository. I am showing a small sample.

```
t.file = "http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/chinese/test.txt";
tfile.conn = file(t.file, open="r", encoding="UTF-8"); # read one line at a time, less memory
lines = readLines(tfile.conn); print(lines);
print(lines);
```

This is not working as I expect.  The output is throwing a warning about the input file:

```
Warning messages:
1: In readLines(tfile.conn) :
  invalid input found on input connection 'http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/chinese/test.txt'
2: In readLines(tfile.conn) :
  incomplete final line found on 'http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/chinese/test.txt'
```

Please advise.

How to read Chinese characters in text file using `readLines`?

If the file is "corrupt", how to update it, so it is not corrupt?

http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/chinese/test.txt

```
Holy Bible, Chinese Union Version (Big5), Textfile 970510
Gen 1:1 起初　神創造天地。
Gen 1:2 地是空虛混沌．淵面黑暗．　神的靈運行在水面上。
Gen 1:3 　神說、要有光、就有了光。
Gen 1:4 　神看光是好的、就把光暗分開了。
```

---

I want to emphasize that there is `zh-cn` and `zh-tw`.  The first is simplified Chinese; the latter is traditional Chinese.

The text file offered is `zh-tw`.

In RStudio, after reading in the line as suggested, I get the following:

```
\xc4@�D�C�q�����f�B�`�P���t�{�P�b�C�\xfc�̡C"
```

which also displays as:

```
"挼㸴@愼㸵D愼㹤C戼㹦q愼㹡戼㹡愼㹥愼㸶戼㸴f愼㸱B戼㸱`戼㹢P戼㸲戼㸳戼㸸t愼㹥{愼㸶P愼㸶b愼㸱C愼㹡昼㹣愼㹤̡C"
```

and when placed in a dataframe, displays as:

```
<U+633C><U+3E34>@<U+613C><U+3E35>D<U+613C><U+3E64>C<U+623C><U+3E66>q<U+613C><U+3E61><U+623C><U+3E61><U+613C><U+3E65><U+613C><U+3E36><U+623C><U+3E34>f<U+613C><U+3E31>B<U+623C><U+3E31>`<U+623C><U+3E62>P<U+623C><U+3E32><U+623C><U+3E33><U+623C><U+3E38>t<U+613C><U+3E65>{<U+613C><U+3E36>P<U+613C><U+3E36>b<U+613C><U+3E31>C<U+613C><U+3E61><U+663C><U+3E63><U+613C><U+3E64><U+0321>C
```

where the TRUE value that was read in is:

```
願主耶穌的恩惠、常與眾聖徒同在。阿們。
```

I am thinking about changing the `locale`, but I only see one option `zh`.  Any ideas on how to read Chinese characters into R that works?

My current locale:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

In RStudio->Tools->Global Options->Code->Saving I have the enviroment set to UTF-8.  I am getting 3 different versions of the result, and they are all different and wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `readr::read_lines` which has a better handling of encodings.

```
t.file = "http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/chinese/test.txt";
readr::read_lines(t.file, n_max = 10)
# [1] "Holy Bible, Chinese Union Version (Big5), Textfile 970510"
# [2] "Gen 1:1 起初　神創造天地。"                               
# [3] "Gen 1:2 地是空虛混沌．淵面黑暗．　神的靈運行在水面上。"   
# [4] "Gen 1:3 　神說、要有光、就有了光。"                       
# [5] "Gen 1:4 　神看光是好的、就把光暗分開了。"
```

Comment: this is a nice solution!

Comment: `read_lines` doesn't pass in "encoding" or "locale", is that why it works?  I would prefer to understand what is going on under the hood of `read_lines` to make this work.  That means, understand how "base" is reacting.  The function is calling `read_lines_` which I can't immediately see, looks like this: `https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/master/src/read.cpp`

Comment: I think it's simply making a good guess that the file is UTF-8, whereas `readLines` uses the wrong one. I actually get the right output with an explicit `readLines(t.file, encoding = "UTF-8")`.